# laravel Eloquent Relations can't access Property

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have got these three models with relations:

**class Comment**

```
class Comment extends Eloquente {

  use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

  protected $table = 'comments';


  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo ('User');
  }

  public function post()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Post');
  }
}
```

**class User**

```
class User extends Eloquent  {
  use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

  /**
  * The database table used by the model.
  *
  * @var string
  */
  protected $table = 'users';

  /**
  * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
  *
  * @var array
  */
  protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

  public function post()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
  }

  public function comment()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Comment');
  }
}
```

**class Post**

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
  use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

  /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'posts';

  /**
   * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
   *
   * @var array
  */
  protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


  public function comment()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Comment');
  }
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
  }
}
```

In controller Simply

```
return View::make('viewfile',['feed'=> Post::all()]);
```

view file:

```
@foreach($feed as $post)

     @foreach($post->comment as $comment)
        {{$comment->user->username}}
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

In view file it returns that is undefined property 
`if var_dump() ;` return only true
but if I put this `foreach` loops in controller function and 
return value `$comment->user->username`, it return name of user
so my question is what should I do to be able to use this property
in view file

Controller

```
<?php

class BoardController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            $followers_count = sizeof(unserialize(Auth::user()->Followers));
            $following_count = sizeof(unserialize(Auth::user()->Following));
            $following_groups_count = sizeof(unserialize(Auth::user()->GroupsFollowing));
            $feed = Post::all();

            foreach ($feed as $post) {

                foreach($post->comment as $comment)
                {
                    return $comment->user->username;
                }
            }


             /*

            return View::make('board.index',[
                    'FollowersCount' => $followers_count,
                    'FollowingCount' => $following_count,
                    'FollowingGroupsCount' => $following_groups_count,
                    'feed' => $feed,
                    'nick' => Auth::user()->username
                ]);
            */
        }
        else
        {
            Redirect::to('/login');
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: Is it possible that some comments don't have a user assigned? Try: `{{ ($comment->user ? $comment->user->username : '') }}`

Comment: Nope, there is one comment in DB  , and have assigned user ,
when i print this from controller it's output the user name

Comment: Okay. Can you add the code that works in your controller to the question?

Comment: Well in the controller you return the (first) `$comment->user->username`. My suspicion is that the loop would run more then once causing an error in the 2nd, 3rd iteration or so... Do you get an error if you do `echo $comment->user->username` instead of `return`?

Comment: Oh and by the way, I'm pretty sure your `Comment` and `Post` model don't need the `UserTrait` and `RemindableTrait`. Those are only meant for user models...